# the empty file keeps reseting

Tags: java, file

every time I write anything in an empty file and run  the main method the whole empty file gets erased

```
package assignment1;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestFoodProduct {

 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader ("food.data"));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter ("food.data");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to `pw.print` or anything like that. Are you sure you're even printing your data? If so, can we please see the whole code?

Comment: Your file is getting overwritten because you are reading and writing to the same file (though you don't actually read or write anything in your code yet).

Comment: @Nex That's not necessarily why the file is overwritten. It's only because `new PrintWriter(String)` alone clears the file. The scanner is irrelevant, but will certainly cause other issues